# Easy way to reverse String

Tags: java, string

Without going through the char sequence is there any way to reverse `String` in Java

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this,

```
String s = "responses";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
System.out.println(builder.reverse());
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [`StringBuilder#reverse()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29):

```
String reverse = new StringBuilder(originalString).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `StringBuilder's` or `StringBuffer's` method... `reverse()`

```
 public class StringReverse
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  String string=args[0];
  String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
  System.out.println("\nString before reverse: "+string);
  System.out.println("String after reverse: "+reverse);
  } 
}
```

`StringBuffer` is **thread-safe**, where as `StringBuilder` is **Not thread safe**..... `StringBuilder` **was introduced from Java 1.5**, as to do those operations faster which doesn't have any Concurrency to worry about....

Comment: Sorry...by mistake i missed the Builder and Buffer part

Comment: You should use StringBuilder vs. StringBuffer, unless you have concurrency problems to solve.

Comment: Added the diff b/w Builder and Buffer

Answer (score 5):

Try reverse() method:

```
StringBuilder stringName = new StringBuilder();
String reverse = stringName.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Are you sure that this method exists? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, the question it´s not correctly answered

Answer (score 3):

You may use StringBuilder..

```
String word = "Hello World!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);

System.out.print(sb.reverse());
```

Answer (score 3):

If we have to do it:

> Without going through the char sequence

One easy way with iteration will be:

```
public String reverse(String post) {                
    String backward = "";
    for(int i = post.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        backward += post.substring(i, i + 1);
    }        
    return backward;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use String buffer to reverse a string.

```
public String reverse(String s) {
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
}
```

one more interesting way to do this is recursion.

```
public String reverse(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1) { 
        return s;
    }
    return reverse(s.substring(1, s.length())) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do so using recursion -

```
public static String reverse(String s1){
        int l = s1.length();
        if (l>1)
                return(s1.substring(l-1) + reverse(s1.substring(0,l-1)));
        else
                return(s1.substring(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using minimal API support. A simple algorithm.

```
static String reverse(String str) {
    char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length/2; ++i){
        char c = buffer[i];
        buffer[i] = buffer[buffer.length-1-i];
        buffer[buffer.length-1-i] = c;
    }
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Please read the question again. How do you understand `Without going through the char sequence`?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a sample of the same using substring method and o(n) without using any nethods from string . I am aware that using substring will hold complete string memory.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)    {
    s = s.substring(1, s.length() - i) + s.charAt(0) + s.substring(s.length() - i);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This might help you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RevString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="jagan";
    String rev="";
    for (int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
      rev=rev+s.charAt(i);
    }
     System.out.println("Reverse String is: "+rev);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just the same logic as nazar_art's answer from 2013.

Answer (score 0):

**I have not seen any easy way.**
**Here is the suitable way to do:**

---

Using the loop:

---

```
    String d = "abcdefghij";
    char b[] = new char[d.length()];// new array;
    int j=0; // for the array indexing
    for(int i=d.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        b[j] = d.charAt(i); // input the last value of d in first of b i.e. b[0] = d[n-1]
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println("The reverse string is: "+String.valueOf(b));
```

---

**Output is**
`The reverse string is: jihgfedcba`

---

The simple logic is:

`array[i] = array[n-i];`
        where i is the Iteration and n is the total length of array

Comment: Please read the question again. How do you understand `Without going through the char sequence`?

Comment: Another way to reverse string as you mention @nazar_art.