# String reverse using Java'sstringbuilder

Tags: java, string, reverse, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I develop using Java to make a little project.

I want String reverse.
If I entered "I am a girl", Printed reversing...

Already I tried to use StringBuilder.
Also I write it using StringBuffer grammar... 
But I failed...
It is not printed my wish...

*WISH*

My with Print -> "I ma a lrig"

**"I am a girl" -> "I ma a lrig"** REVERSE!!

How can I do?..

Please help me thank you~!!!

```
public String reverse() {        
    String[] words = str.split("\\s");       
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");

    for (String string : words) {
        System.out.print(string);
    }

    String a = Arrays.toString(words);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(a);

    System.out.println(words[0]);

    for (String st : words){
        System.out.print(st);
    }

    return "";     
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305693/3145960

Comment: The OP doesn't want  entire String to be reversed, she wants each token (separated by space) to be reversed.

Comment: There is a reverse() method already in the StringBuilder. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 code to do this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "I am a girl";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // split() returns an array of Strings, for each string, append it to a StringBuilder by adding a space.
    Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+")).stream().forEach(s -> {
        sb.append(new StringBuilder(s).reverse() + " ");
    });
    String reversed = sb.toString().trim(); // remove trailing space
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

O/P :

```
I ma a lrig
```

Comment: @한송송이 - Its called lambda expression. You can read about them :)

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to go with `lambda` then you can try this solution too

```
String str = "I am a girl";
        String finalString = "";
        String s[] = str.split(" ");
        for (String st : s) {
            finalString += new StringBuilder(st).reverse().append(" ").toString();
        }
        System.out.println(finalString.trim());
    }
```